# My Header resize on scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have done this on other sites but I can't seem to get this to work on this site.
It should shrink a little bit and the header background color should become white as you scroll down the page.  Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 150,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

and here is my css -

.page-id-10 header {

```
background: transparent;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0s ease 0s, all 0.25s ease 0s;
height: auto;
```

}

header {

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0s ease 0s, all 0.25s ease 0s;
height: auto;
```

}

header.smaller {

```
height: auto;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
```

}

header.smaller .logo img {

```
    max-width: 250px;
```

}

## top-header-section {

```
width: 100%; 
padding: 0 10px 0 22px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

header.smaller #access {

```
background-color: none;
```

}

header.smaller #access a {

```
line-height: 10px;
```

}

The url is http://pt6-dev.info/

Thank you!!

Comment: what is `classie`?

Comment: A lots of `classie is not defined` are logged at console.

Comment: I found the script here - https://brentstromberg.com/sticky-header-classie-js/

Comment: then make sure to add that file as part of your project/page. It seems to be you forgot to do that.

Comment: You mean a file besides the javascipt I have in the header?

Comment: Yes, the file that loads that utility library.

Comment: I added it in the header but that didn't fix it.  The same exact code works on this site https://answergroup.net but I can't figure out why it won't work on this one.

Comment: Are you sure? I can see it working now.

Comment: Try with a solid color, like black. Do not use a transpareancy so you can check. Make sure to remove browser cache first.

Comment: Wow it all of a sudden started to work!  Thank you so much!!  So is there an easy way to swap logo images when it scrolls down?  I need to add a darker one but I'm not sure how to do that.  Should I set the logo as a background image or is there an easier way?